# How to mixing two dictionaries in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the following dictionaries:

```
dict1={'fx245': 2, 'gt345': 12, 'vf251': 1, 'js921': 3}
dict2={'fx245': 'Alex', 'gt345': 'Peter', 'vf251': 'Louis', 'js921': 'Alice'}
```

The question is: how to link the both dictionaries?. For example like:

The code fx245, ie Alex, has the number 2.

Help and thanks

Comment: Define link.  Do you want to get a single dictionary where the value is a tuple, so that `dict3[fx245]` returns `(2, 'Alex')`?

Comment: Is this homework, BTW? You don't seem to understand your own problem.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski I'm trying to get a list of phrases :                               The code fx245, ie Alex, has the number 2.
The code gt345, ie Peter, has the number 12.
The code vf251, ie Louis, has the number 1.
The code js921, ie Alice, has the number 3.

Comment: @KemyLand It is for a project I'm doing but still I can not understand python altogether

Comment: @Python241820:  You're speaking in English, not in code.  What do you want the resulting data structure to look like *in Python*?  Or at least describe how you want to use your data structure.  Something like I have `'fx245` and I want to get `'Alex'`.  Or I have `'Alex'` and I want to get `2`.  Or I have `'fx245` and I want to get `'Alex'` and `2`.  Something like that.

Comment: @StevenRumbalskiI have a code and want to get a name and his number. And print the code , name and number of the 4 people

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given

```
dict1 = {'fx245': 2, 'gt345': 12, 'vf251': 1, 'js921': 3}
dict2 = {'fx245': 'Alex', 'gt345': 'Peter', 'vf251': 'Louis', 'js921': 'Alice'}
```

Create a third dict that maps the code to both the name and number:

```
dict3 = {k:(v, dict1[k]) for k, v in dict2.items()}
```

Here it is in action:

```
>>> dict3['fx245']
('Alex', 2)
>>> name, num = dict3['fx245']
>>> name
'Alex'
>>> num
2
```

You mention in the comments that you want to iterate over the new dictionary and print the code, name and number.  Do it like so:

```
for code, (name, num) in dict3.items(): 
    print(code, name, num)
```

Comment: Exactly that's what I wanted to achieve. Sorry for the misunderstanding and thank you very much :)

Answer (score 2):

Make a new dict, using a dict comprehension:

```
from collections import namedtuple

dict1 = {'fx245': 2, 'gt345': 12, 'vf251': 1, 'js921': 3}
dict2 = {'fx245': 'Alex', 'gt345': 'Peter', 'vf251': 'Louis', 'js921': 'Alice'}

Person = namedtuple('Person', 'name number')

all_keys = dict1.viewkeys() & dict2.viewkeys()  # just use .keys() on py3
dictmix = {k: Person(dict2.get(k), dict1.get(k)) for k in all_keys}
```

Demo:

```
>>> dictmix['fx245']
Person(name='Alex', number=2)
>>> dictmix['fx245'].name
'Alex'
>>> dictmix['fx245'].number
2
```